# Heroku assets precompile fails for i18n-js

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, i18n-gem

On pushing the Rails4 code to heroku I get the following error, this has started happening in last 2 days, which otherwise a smooth process

```
 Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
  -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   couldn't find file '/tmp/build_b6402ff8-bda2-4bc5-95dc-2efe7a9044bc/tmp/i18n-js.cache'
   (in /tmp/build_b6402ff8-bda2-4bc5-95dc-2efe7a9044bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/vendor/assets/javascripts/i18n/translations.js.erb)
   /tmp/build_b6402ff8-bda2-4bc5-95dc-2efe7a9044bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:87:in `resolve'
```

Here is entry from my production.rb

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```

I am able to run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` locally. Though I am not pushing the precompiled assets to the server.

I am get I18n-js 2.1.2 version installed through my gem files, its Rails4 server running for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of i18n-js rails gem, to get the problem fixed.
I was using it minimally so replaced it with some small code of mine.

There are problems with the Gem and Rails 4 when deploying on Heroku.

Answer (score 6):

Bumping up the asset version seems to work. Change the following line in *application.rb*:

```
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Comment: This worked for me ! None of the other solutions worked). I had git://github.com/torandi/i18n-js.git (at rails4) as dependency

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks. Reported it at Github:https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js/issues/189

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your tmp folder using the following rake task:

```
rake tmp:clear
```

This will allow Heroku to do a fresh precompile of all of your assets.

Comment: on heroku console not just the local before pushing, as the local one does not help ?

Comment: rake tmp:clear locally before push, did hereoku run rake tmp:clear --app XXXXXXXX  error remains the same.

Comment: You may need to clear your local tmp as well, since those files will be pushed to heroku when you push your app up.

Comment: Perhaps try rake assets:clean

Comment: If I drop i18n-js it compiles the assets though page has errors in Javascript.

Comment: Its funny, I removed i18n-js and pushed it to heroku it worked and readding I pushed again it works. Seems like it caused some caching to be cleared. Otherwise heroku run rake assets:clean, heroku run tmp:clear is also not helping.